# circom error in zk-rollup circuit: circom error: circuit too big for this power of tau ceremony. 6600*2 > 2**12

Tags: zksnark, rollups, merkleization, circom

while making zk rollup circuit of merkle, i got this error.
[image: circuit]

code for .circom:

```
pragma circom 2.0.3;
include "modules/mimicsponge.circom";

// ref: https://github.com/4undRaiser/circom_merkletree

template Merkle_Tree (n) {
   signal input leaves[n]; // taking in the input as a list of n leaves(in this case it is assumed that the number of leaves is 4)
   signal output root;  // output as a merkle root
   var N = n*2-1;
   signal hashes[N];
   component components[N];
    var j = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(i < n) {
            // putting the hashes into leaves
            components[i] = MiMCSponge(1, 220, 1);
            components[i].k <== i;
            components[i].ins[0] <== leaves[i];
        } else {
            // constructing the merkle tree
            components[i] = MiMCSponge(2, 220, 1);
            components[i].k <== i;
            components[i].ins[0] <== hashes[j];
            components[i].ins[1] <== hashes[j+1];
            j+=2;
        }
        hashes[i] <== components[i].outs[0];
    }

    // getting the hash of the merkle root
    root <== hashes[N-1];
}

// var public transactionsPerBatch=4;
component main {public [leaves]} = Merkle_Tree(4);
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Ethereum. I doubt we have many Circom experts around here

Comment: Circom is used to make zk rollups in sidechain. rollups are most settled on ethereum blockchain only.
so this is a question of ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

i just met this bug, you have to change the pot key to expand limit of constraints (2^12 in your case). the command that i use to create pot is below:
snarkjs powersoftau new bn128 14 pot12_0000.ptau -v
the limit of constraints is 2^14 now.